# Script behavior changes if browser is headless or not

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

I wrote a web scraping program on python (with selenium) which works very well. The last step was to add a headless functionality.
The problem is that when the script is running headless, at a specific moment (when it should click over a link to refresh the page), terminal gives me this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="prtl.refresh(this);">...</a> is not clickable at point (217, 157). Other element would receive the click: <span ewnet:toggler="290" class="prtl">...</span>
```

The weird thing is that when the same script is not headless, selenium doesn't throw the error and all goes perfectly.

I have tried to reach the element using several methods but same error.

This is when the script decides if the browser is headless or not:

```
# create driver
if headless:
    chromedriver = './chromedriver'
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = chromedriver, chrome_options = options)
else:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
```

The element I'm trying to click looks something like this:

```html
<a href='some_url' onclick='refresh(this)'>
<span class='name'>refresh page!</span>
</a>
```

and my script searches it by `xpath` on `<a>` tag.

Comment: Try setting up a window size even if it's headless.

Comment: In headless mode, what error selenium throw? Can you please share the details of exception.

Comment: @Zohair in top of the post the exact exception is detailed

Comment: @SergioPulgarin it worked! could you please tell me why this option changes something? i read that window size was optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to ensure that the window size is large enough for the objects to be clickable otherwise the window-size property is set to 0x0 and the objects will be covering each other:

`options.add_argument('window-size=2000x1500')`

So to code will look like this:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=2000x1500')
```

This works for `chromedriver`. I have not checked other headless browsers, but expect the same or similar behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a window size even if it's headless.

I don't remember this exactly, but I had the same error a couple of years back when I was writing End to End tests on selenium. I think it still needs a viewport size, probably the engine optimizes it to 0x0 by default if headless (?).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before when running Selenium in a Java project. I solved it, by setting the

```
window.size = 1980x1080
```

However this time in VBA, I had to set

```
driver.Window.SetSize 2000, 1500
```

, to get the same behavior from the headless browser

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).